# Implementing DUKPT Key Management

Tags: .net, security

I am currently looking to implement [DUKPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_unique_key_per_transaction) (Derived Unique Key per Transaction) and am lost on how to successfully implement it. Does anyone know a step-by-step guide/existing implementation out there, or some more information on the actual implementation of the solution in a client-server application?

An introduction to DUKPT:

> In cryptography, Derived Unique Key
>   Per Transaction (DUKPT) is a key
>   management scheme in which for every
>   transaction, a unique key is used
>   which is derived from a fixed key.
>   Therefore, if a derived key is
>   compromised, future and past
>   transaction data are still protected
>   since the next or prior keys cannot be
>   determined easily. DUKPT is specified
>   in ANSI X9.24 part 1.
>
> DUKPT allows the processing of the
>   encryption to be moved away from the
>   devices that hold the shared secret.
>   The encryption is done with a derived
>   key, which is not re-used after the
>   transaction. DUKPT is used to encrypt
>   electronic commerce transactions.
>   While it can be used to protect
>   information between two companies or
>   banks, it is typically used to encrypt
>   PIN information acquired by
>   Point-Of-Sale (POS) devices. DUKPT is
>   not itself an encryption standard;
>   rather it is a key management
>   technique. The features of the DUKPT
>   scheme are:
>
> - Enable both originating and receiving parties to be in agreement
>     as to the key being  used for a given
>     transaction,
> - Each transaction will have a distinct key from all other
>     transactions, except by coincidence,
> - If a present key is compromised, past and future keys (and thus the
>     transactional data encrypted under
>     them) remain uncompromised,
> - Each device generates a different key sequence,
> - Originators and receivers of encrypted messages do not have to
>     perform an interactive key-agreement
>     protocol beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting protocol,  it is also exotic.   The Jpos project has working [java code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#hbrsPV2tzMY/jpos6/modules/jpos/src/org/jpos/security/EncryptedPIN.java&q=dukpt&sa=N&cd=5&ct=rc) of DUKPT.   I think the best place to start is with a already working implementation.

If you are implementing a real world system perhaps [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) would be better suited to your needs.

Comment: Even if you implement DUKPT in another language, you could benefit from jPOS' test cases https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/test/java/org/jpos/security/jceadapter/DUKPTTest.java

Answer (score 3):

I recently went through the same pains which resulted in this iOS DUKPT implementation.

https://github.com/mburshteyn1/DUKPT

Answer (score 0):

DUKPT is explained in ANSI X9.24 specs, including pretty straight forward pseudo code that you can implement in any language.